# Android: implemented HeaderListView, cannot access RowItem

Tags: java, android

I am using HeaderListView (http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/) to add sticky headers to ListView. Everything works very well, but I am not able to find out which item was clicked. Unfortunately they don't show this in their demo application.

I found on their website that I need to use the onRowItemClick method, but not sure how to call it. What I have so far:

```
SectionListAdapter bindingData = new SectionListAdapter(c, inflater, 3); //SectionListAdapter extends SectionAdapter
articleList.setAdapter(bindingData); //articleList = HeaderListView

// Click event for single list row
articleList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onRowItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int section, int row, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClass(getActivity(), ArticleActivity.class);

    // Pass object to next activity

    startActivity(i);
}
});
```

What am I do wrong in the following line?

```
articleList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the source code, it appears you have to create your custom adapter class (ex: MyCustomSectionAdapter, perhaps this is your 'SectionListAdapter').

In this class you implement the method:

```
public void onRowItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int section, int row, long id) {


}
```

Which should then be called, I guess.

**EDIT:**

I've downloaded the code, and it didn't work for me either.

After adding the following code on line 40 to the HeaderListView class, it did work.

```
   mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (mAdapter != null)
                mAdapter.onItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        }
    });
```

It appears as if the click connection was never made. Find it kinda strange and I guess there should be another solution, but this works for now.

Code license: http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/#license

Comment: Correct and onRowItemClick is implemented, but my question was about the following line: articleList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnClickListener(), which does not compile because setOnItemClickListener is not defined for HeaderListView, what to use instead?

Comment: I don't think you should put any clickListener on the articleList, instead implement your code inside the OnRowItemClick in the adapter.

Comment: Ok understood, I implemented the onRowItemClick(...) method within my adapter class, but still it is not called. Don't I need to tell articleList to call this method? Sorry for asking so many questions, but this HeaderListView class is really not documented well.

Comment: Edited answer in reply

Comment: What did you add to the HeaderListView? Line 40 in the HeaderListView.java is an empty line outside of any method, therefore the above code snippet will not compile.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed I forgot to add an OnItemClickListener. The issue has now been fixed on the github repo.